# React Native fetch array json data

Tags: react-native

I am pulling data from Mysql to React native. As you can see, the output of the data I have captured is in the array. How can I pull Array data? With the code below, I can pull the data into an array. For example, I want to extract the `new_image` variable from the array.

```
  getBusinessNewsData() {
fetch('...').then((response) => response.json())
    .then((findresponse)=>{
  var newSearch = findresponse.new_image;
        console.log(newSearch)

      this.setState({
        data:newSearch,
      })

    })
```

```
[
       {
          "id":"..",
          "new_date":"...",
          "new_title":"...",
          "new_slug":"...",
          "new_url":"",
          "new_image":"...",
          "new_fixed":"..."
       }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the response and extract `new_image`

```
const result = findResponse.map((d) => d.new_image);
```

Then you can set `result` in component internal state.

Answer (score 0):

If the `console.log(newSearch)` gives you the array above and you want to have the new_image property then you can set a state like `this.setState({ newImage: newSearch[0].new_image })`

By doing so `this.state.newImage` would be the value from the array.

Comment: But there it only shoots the first array. I also want to pull news_image's assigned values ​​in 1.2.3.

Comment: For that you can use the FlatList Component React Native provides. It takes the Data as an Array and gives you back a component for every entry (object) inside the array.